# I got "stack level too deep" error when saving / creating an instance in Rails 3 and mongoid environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stack-trace

I got "stack level too deep" error when saving / creating an instance in Rails 3 and mongoid environment?

No errors:

```
@nameq = Question.new(:survey_id => @survey.id, :title => 'Example Question', :required_question => true, :input => 'string', :uuid => Time.now.to_i, :position => 1)
```

Errors "stack level too deep"

```
@nameq = Question.create(:survey_id => @survey.id, :title => 'Example Question', :required_question => true, :input => 'string', :uuid => Time.now.to_i, :position => 1)
```

What's common reasons in this situation?

Comment: stack level too deep is usually the result of an infinite recursion, maybe you have some save callback which itself calls save?

Comment: Is there any stacktrace available? Not everything, but only the part that is not repeating.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have some after_save callback in your model which causes this result

Comment: You asked this same question yesterday (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917411/i-got-stack-level-too-deep-error-when-i-add-following-code-in-my-controller-h) and more details were requested and yet have not been provided. The stack trace would probably provide a good clue to what's happening. If you can give us the additional information, I'm sure we can help.

Comment: I have added stack trace already in that question. The full trace: vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425 . For more detail stack trace, I don't know how to display it.

Answer (score 0):

1)  catch that error:

begin
  foo
rescue SystemStackError
  puts $!
  puts caller[0..100]
end

2) :autosave => true in two models could be responsible